# Mongodb/Mongoose required field that I've removed long time ago

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a new user but I get this error:

`Unable to add the element, the value null for the field loginPublic already exists, it cannot be duplicated.`

The thing is that this field was used several months ago and I've renamed it since (in my user schema). I couldn't find any reference to this field in my project neither in the mongo database.

I'm wondering if it's possible that some kind of caching is messing up, checking the existence of such field while it's not used in my schema anymore.

Any idea?

Comment: Aren't you using coffee-script and forgot to compile the new file?

Comment: I'm using TypeScript (so basically same kind of thing) and no, the compilation is auto plus I would have found a reference in the `.ts` file if it did exist.

Comment: Have you tried moving the file away from your project? If it's still working, your old file may be still there or you are just require-ing bad file.

Comment: To be sure, I tried on debug mode and took a look to my schema in program memory, the field `loginPublic` is **not** present, so it's not related to a non up-to-date file.

Comment: Use the MongoDB shell to check for a unique index on that collection that references `loginPublic`.

Comment: Ohhhh, true, there where an index there.

Answer (score 0):

It was an index issue:

List: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/list-indexes/

Remove: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-indexes/

`db.user.getIndexes()`

```
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "loginPublic" : 1
            },
            "unique" : true,
            "ns" : "ayolan-translation-development.user",
            "name" : "loginPublic_1",
            "background" : true,
            "safe" : null
    },
```

The index on the "deleted" (non-used anymore) field still exist:

`db.user.dropIndex( "loginPublic_1" )`

*Thanks to JohnnyHK.*